How to declare a type with one of its properties being a dictionary where a key is excluded based upon the value of another property?
I've got an AuthStatus enum like:
enum AuthStatus {
  UNAUTHENTICATED,
  ONBOARDING,
  AUTHENTICATED
}

Now, I would like to declare a type as following:
type AuthType<T extends AuthStatus> = {
  accepted: T,
  navigateTo: Record<T, string>
}

where the navigateTo property should be a Record with the keys of the enum values, but excluding the one we choose as accepted.
For example:
/* 'exampleA' accepts 'UNAUTHENTICATED' users.
'UNAUTHENTICATED' should be excluded from the 'navigateTo' object.
*/
const exampleA: AuthType<AuthStatus> = {
  accepted: AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED,
  navigateTo: {
    [AuthStatus.ONBOARDING]: '/onboarding',
    [AuthStatus.AUTHENTICATED]: '/',
  }
}

/* 'exampleB' accepts 'ONBOARDING' users.
'ONBOARDING' should be excluded from the 'navigateTo' object.
*/
const exampleB: AuthType<AuthStatus> = {
  accepted: AuthStatus.ONBOARDING,
  navigateTo: {
    [AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED]: '/login',
    [AuthStatus.AUTHENTICATED]: '/',
  }
}

/* 'exampleC' accepts 'AUTHENTICATED' users.
'AUTHENTICATED' should be excluded from the 'navigateTo' object.
*/
const exampleC: AuthType<AuthStatus> = {
  accepted: AuthStatus.AUTHENTICATED,
  navigateTo: {
    [AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED]: '/login',
    [AuthStatus.ONBOARDING]: '/onboarding',
  }
}

How to declare the AuthType to make sure the keys of the record excludes the accepted value?

Does the approach in this playground link meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (and do you need to have AuthType be generic? What's wrong with this approach?)

Awesome. Both solutions do solve my issue. There is currently no need for the generic type, but I do see a use case for it, when the type is provided by a library and could by implemented with a custom enum. Very clever approach anyway. Thanks a lot.

Hmm, I'm confused how a custom enum would work since you have T extends AuthStatus. Presumably you just want something like T extends PropertyKey instead? I'll write that version.

I'd say you want AuthType<T> to be a union where for each member of the union T, there's a member of the union AuthType<T> where that member is accepted and where navigateTo has all keys in T except that member. You can write it as a distributive object type (as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109), a mapped type into which you index:
type AuthType<T extends PropertyKey> = { [K in T]: {
    accepted: K,
    navigateTo: Record<Exclude<T, K>, string>
} }[T]

The important bit there is the Exclude utility type which filters union members.  For AuthStatus that becomes
type AuthTypeForAuthStatus = AuthType<AuthStatus>
/* type AuthTypeForAuthStatus = {
    accepted: AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED;
    navigateTo: Record<AuthStatus.ONBOARDING | AuthStatus.AUTHENTICATED, string>;
} | {
    accepted: AuthStatus.ONBOARDING;
    navigateTo: Record<AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED | AuthStatus.AUTHENTICATED, string>;
} | {
    accepted: AuthStatus.AUTHENTICATED;
    navigateTo: Record<AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED | AuthStatus.ONBOARDING, string>;
} */

as desired. Or for some other set of keys:
type Test = AuthType<"a" | "b" | "c" | "d">;
/* type Test = {
    accepted: "a";
    navigateTo: Record<"b" | "c" | "d", string>;
} | {
    accepted: "b";
    navigateTo: Record<"a" | "c" | "d", string>;
} | {
    accepted: "c";
    navigateTo: Record<"a" | "b" | "d", string>;
} | {
    accepted: "d";
    navigateTo: Record<"a" | "b" | "c", string>;
} */

Your examples then work as written:
const exampleA: AuthType<AuthStatus> = {
    accepted: AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED,
    navigateTo: {
        [AuthStatus.ONBOARDING]: '/onboarding',
        [AuthStatus.AUTHENTICATED]: '/',
    }
} // okay, etc

Playground link to code

Can I ask, if 'accepted' would be an array of possible options, can you achieve the same and exclude all accepted options from the record keys?

Maybe? It's out of scope here and in order to discuss it we'd need actual [mre] code in a new question. TS doesn't have the concept of an exhaustive array, so Array<"a" | "b"> might be empty for all TS knows. A union of all possible tuples of options (without repeats) would scale very badly in the number of options (with repeats it's just infinite), so unless you know you're only going to have a handful (like 4 or so) options then you might need to make a generic type and helper function instead and... there's not room here to discuss this.

Use Exclude to exclude accepted key from Record
Exclude<AuthStatus, T>

Write a specific type so that TypeScript understands what needs to be used and what needs to be excluded
AuthType<AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED>

Full example
enum AuthStatus {
  UNAUTHENTICATED,
  ONBOARDING,
  AUTHENTICATED
}

type AuthType<T extends AuthStatus> = {
  accepted: T;
  navigateTo: Record<Exclude<AuthStatus, T>, string>;
}

const navigateToExample: AuthType<AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED> = {
  accepted: AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED,
  navigateTo: {
    [AuthStatus.ONBOARDING]: '/onboarding',
    [AuthStatus.AUTHENTICATED]: '/',
    [AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED]: '/6', // TS2353: Object literal may only specify known properties, and [AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED] does not exist in type
  }
}

const acceptedExample: AuthType<AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED> = {
  accepted: AuthStatus.ONBOARDING, // TS2322: Type AuthStatus.ONBOARDING is not assignable to type AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED
  navigateTo: {
    [AuthStatus.ONBOARDING]: '/onboarding',
    [AuthStatus.AUTHENTICATED]: '/',
  }
}

const goodExample: AuthType<AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED> = {
  accepted: AuthStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED,
  navigateTo: {
    [AuthStatus.ONBOARDING]: '/onboarding',
    [AuthStatus.AUTHENTICATED]: '/',
  }
}

